# Javascript onclick trigger function but let default behaviour carry on

Tags: jquery, onclick

Here's the scenario, I have a page with a button that opens a fancybox iframe window. Within the iframe content is a link that will open in a new window using `target="_blank"`. I would like the click to trigger a javascript function to close the fancybox window as well as opening the new window.

Using jquery I have bound a simple click function that calls `parent.$.fancybox.close();` but this doesn't return the click back to the browser to fire the link in a new window.

I don't want to use `window.open` as it gets blocked 99% of the time, I just need the default behaviour to happen.

How can I call the close function onclick whilst letting the normal behaviour take place?

EDIT

Adding code:

Page that opens the fancybox iframe.

```
<a href="http://something.com" id="OpenIframeLink">open fancybox</a>
<script>
$("#OpenIframeLink").fancybox({
    'padding': '20',
    'width': 450,
    'height': 550,
    'scrolling': 'no',
    'type': 'iframe',
    'href': '/content.asp?url=' + encodeURIComponent($("#OpenIframeLink").attr('href')),
    'showCloseButton': false
});
</script>
```

Now this code is on the content.asp page within the iframe fancybox window

```
<div id="message">
    <a href="http://something.com" target="_blank">click me</a>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#message a').click(function() {
      parent.$.fancybox.close();

      //now it should open the new window as a standard default click
      //as if this function wasn't bound to the click
    });
</script>
```

Comment: can you show code or create a fiddle ?

Comment: Does the page loaded into iframe come from another domain?

Comment: Code added and no it's from the same domain.

Comment: Sorry, your problem has no solution since the page is from another domain. Your page's scripts are not allowed to interact with this kind of page due to cross-origin policy.

Comment: I wasn't clear in my code there. The content within the iframe isn't coming from the href. I'll add more code.

Comment: OK. Why don't you just load the content of something.com directly into the same iframe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this **link**: http://www.techfoobar.com/2012/jquery-programmatically-clicking-a-link-and-forcing-the-default-action

*Disclaimer:* Its an article I have written.

The technique involves creating a `form` element on the fly with the link's `href` as its `action` and the link's `target` as its `target` attribute and then triggering its submit via code (which fortunately the browser allows)